# How to fetch manager name and their profile along with username and userid

Tags: apex, soql, query

Requirement:-I need to fetch userName,UserID along with manager names and manager profileName in single query .

i have used below query but i am not getting manager profileName

```
select userName,UserID,manager.name,manager.Id from user
```

How should i fetch manager-Profile name here 
Please suggest.Urgent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
select userName,id,manager.name,manager.Id, manager.profile.name from user
```